# Error receiving in use of Sumif formula in excel

Tags: excel

I am using sumif formula to create a summary report based on orders received from customers. Formula used is as below -

=SUMIF(CONCATENATE('Order Format'!$F$2:$F$1300,'Order Format'!G$1),CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$43,B$1),'Order Format'!G$2:G$1300)

an error is asking to put single quote before formula. Please help me

[image]

Comment: [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) needs two or three arguments. But first must be a range. You have three but the first is not a range. Only last is a range. What do you think will `CONCATENATE('Order Format'!$F$2:$F$1300,'Order Format'!G$1)` and `CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$43,B$1)` do and return?

Comment: is this an array formula?

Comment: Yes I do, but its not working. I have checked both of them separately

Comment: returning the same thing. Could you please explain me about array formula & how to solve my purpose also.

Comment: "how to solve my purpose": You have not explained what is your purpose. What shall the formula do? As it is, it cannot work.

Comment: So column B in your red bordered sheet needs to show the sum of column G in the other sheet (Order Format) if the Variety in column F of that other sheet is the same as the Variety in column A in the red bordered sheet? `=SUMIF('Order Format'!$F$2:$F$1300, $A2, 'Order Format'!G$2:G$1300)`

Comment: thanks ! its working :-)  Now how to close this question.

Comment: You (Nafis) or @AxelRichter can post the resolution as answer.. then accept and upvote it. || It'll benefit others too. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_: The "solution" is the simplest usage of `SUMIF` as shown in documentation. The question lacks a mention why the OP had tried it that complicated way. So how shall that benefit others too?

Comment: _"..lacks a mention.. "_ that's Nafis part. Just share us how do you develop/build this formula) Or else we can just assume...  ||  "Put the solution as answer.."  will remove this question from 'unanswered' question list. Since this is not identified as [on hold] or [duplicate], to close it will at least assist in not to generate another duplicate/unanswered/forever-open question in the future.. Since Nafis is eager to close it properly. IMHO, it was just proper to help him/her do just that.